# Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tags: rspec, devise, capybara, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Please note, I'm having this error **not when creating** user, but **when editing**.

I believe that email uniqueness's check can be done within the `devise`.

Github repo: https://github.com/tenzan/shop , but `editing_users_spec.rb` is not there yet.

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb
FF

Failures:

  1) Admins can change a user's details with valid details
     Failure/Error: let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Admins can change a user's details when toggling a user's admin ability
     Failure/Error: let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05535 seconds (files took 2.29 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb:13 # Admins can change a user's details with valid details
rspec ./spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb:22 # Admins can change a user's details when toggling a user's admin ability
```

**spec/features/admin/editing_users_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Admins can change a user's details" do
  let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin)}
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

  before do
    login_as(admin_user)
    visit admin_user_path(user)
    click_link 'Edit User'
  end

  scenario 'with valid details' do
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'newuser@example.com'
    click_button 'Update User'

    expect(page).to have_content 'User has been updated.'
    expect(page).to have_content 'newuser@example.com'
    expect(page).not_to have_content user.email
  end

  scenario "when toggling a user's admin ability" do
    check 'Is an admin?'
    click_button 'Update User'

    expect(page).to have_content 'User has been updated.'
    expect(page).to have_content "#{user.email} (Admin)"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your factory for users you have...

```
sequence(:email) { |n| 'test#{n}@example.com' }
```

It should be...

```
sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
```

You need double quotes to do the interpolation of `n`